# Once colors are added to the 'macrocode' environment, why does the color of the 'macrocode' environment change?

Tags: dtx, l3doc

I'm working on translating some LaTeX documents, aiming to distinguish parts of the document by color for ease of reading. For instance, I'd like to assign blue color to macro commands that require explanation, while assigning brown color to package code. However, in the following code snippet (a small portion of xparse.dtx as a MWE), why is one part blue and another part brown, even though these codes are all within one 'macrocode' environment? Looking at the code, it's apparent that <*2ekernel> and </2ekernel> are influencing the colors, but I'm unsure why.

```
% \iffalse meta-comment
\RequirePackage{expl3}[2018-04-12]
%<*driver>
\documentclass[full]{l3doc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{spot}{HTML}{003399}
\definecolor{code}{HTML}{a25e26}
\let\OriginalMF\MacroFont
\def\MacroFont{\color{spot}\OriginalMF}
\pretocmd{\macrocode}{\def\MacroFont{\color{code}\OriginalMF}}{}{}
\AtBeginEnvironment{macrocode}{\def\MacroFont{\color{code}\OriginalMF}}
\AtEndEnvironment{macrocode}{\def\MacroFont{\color{spot}\OriginalMF}}
\begin{document}
  \DocInput{\jobname.dtx}
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
% \section{\pkg{xparse} implementation}
%
%    \begin{macrocode}
%<*2ekernel|package>
%<@@=cmd>
%<*2ekernel>
\def\@parse@version#1/#2/#3#4#5\@nil{%
  \@parse@version@dash#1-#2-#3#4\@nil}
\def\@parse@version@dash#1-#2-#3#4#5\@nil{%
  \if\relax#2\relax\else#1\fi#2#3#4 }
%</2ekernel>
\ExplSyntaxOn
\ExplSyntaxOff
%</2ekernel|package>
%<*package>
\ProvidesExplPackage{xparse}{2023-10-10}{}
  {L3 Experimental document command parser}
%    \end{macrocode}
```

[image]

Comment: well things are not so easy, doc uses \MacroFont and \AltMacroFont and internally also `\macro@font` and the `<...>` markers map them back and forth. Btw: your \AtBeginEnvironment and \AtEndEnvironment settings are senseless, they are overwritten by your other code or simply lost at the end of the environment.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you for your suggestion! I discovered that by including `\def\macro@font{\color{code}\OriginalMF}` in the `\pretocmd` setting, the color of the code before `</2ekernel>` also changed. I'll revisit the definition of `\AltMacroFont` in the `doc-code` document.